# MacBook Pro (16 inch, 2019) froze on install latest update

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, upgrade, big-sur

I'm just click on update button, it said that updating will take few minutes. But now more than 2 hours left. And it is still updating, it is ok or not? I saw this screen

[image]

It still react when I press cmd+L with sound, also it is possible to change the brigthness of keyboard and screen. So I should still wait for update to finish?

Comment: Your inclination to hard shutdown the machine ought to be inversely proportional to the amount of time since your last backup. How full was the drive before you started?

Comment: @Tetsujin It is a new machine first booted less than a week ago, so drive was almost empty, there is 400Gb+ of free space

Comment: Then I'd be inclined to leave it til morning. If it's not finished, see what happens if you hard shutdown. If all else fails, just restore from backup.

Answer (score 1):

Hard shutdown after 5 hours of waiting solve the problem. System was updated after boot up

Comment: Glad it worked for you… eventually :)